# Hide/Show a UITableView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I need to show/hide a `UITableView` in some situations .But it is running absolutely fine sometimes.But sometimes `tableView` is not hidden.

If array data is present I'm filling it in UITableView.But if the array is null I m displaying a label with text "Data not found"..This is working perfectly ,but if I repeatedly do it then on my TableView's data labels text is getting displayed without hiding the `tableView`..Couldn't understand where I m going wrong..

This is the code I m writing...

```
if([arr count]==0)
{
    lblError.text=@"";
    lblError  = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [lblError setFrame:CGRectMake(0,390,320,200)];
    lblError.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    lblError.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblError.text = @"Results not found";
    lblError.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lblError.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    lblError.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Italic" size:15];      
    [self.view addSubview:lblError];
    tableView.hidden=YES;
    [tableView removeFromSuperview];
    tableView=nil;

 }
else
{
     sections=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int s=0;s<1;s++)
    {
        NSMutableArray *section=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int i=0;i<[arr1 count];i++)
        {
            Item *item=[[Item alloc] init];
            NSString *name=[[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Name"];
            item.Name=name;
            [section addObject:item];

        }
        [sections addObject:section];

    }
    tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,430,320,200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];  
    [tableView release];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by fist allocating tableView's delegate and dataSource to nil and then creating it again

```
tableView.delegate = nil;
tableView.dataSource = nil;

if([arr count]==0)
{
lblError.text=@"";
lblError  = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[lblError setFrame:CGRectMake(0,390,320,200)];
lblError.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
lblError.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblError.text = @"Results not found";
lblError.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
lblError.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lblError.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Italic" size:15];      
[self.view addSubview:lblError];
tableView.hidden=YES;
[tableView removeFromSuperview];
tableView=nil;

}
else
{
 sections=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int s=0;s<1;s++)
{
    NSMutableArray *section=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0;i<[arr1 count];i++)
    {
        Item *item=[[Item alloc] init];
        NSString *name=[[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Name"];
        item.Name=name;
        [section addObject:item];

    }
    [sections addObject:section];

}
tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,430,320,200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];  
[tableView release];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you allocating your `TableView` in the `else` method ? You should simply allocate the `TableView` in the `ViewDidLoad` or the `ViewWillAppear`. Then hide it or unhide it according to your needs. Also dont remove the `TableView` .

Comment: I did it as u have said.But still no luck

Comment: The concept is I have to select a date from DatePicker and for that corresponding date if data exists I will fil it in tableview.Otherwise I will display a simplemessage "Data not found".So I m writing it here -(void)DatePickerDoneClick:(id)sender 
{}.It is working absolutely fine for 4 to 5 times.But if I repeat it more times then tableView is not getting hidden and message is getting displayed on the tableView i.e one on the other ..So what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

try this in a condition where you want to hide

```
tableName.hidden = YES;
```

try this for unhide/show

```
tableName.hidden = NO;
```